# Sourcing data from SQL using lists in Power BI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-datasource

I have to source data from a SQL Server database in Power BI and I am using where clause in my query. I have created a Power BI list which has hundreds of IDs (integer type) and when I use text.combine M function to combine the list values & separate them by a comma I run into datatype issue. Does anyone know what query to use make a list of integers comma separated and use in where clause.

> Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value 2382874 to type Text.
> Details:
> Value=2382874
> Type=[Type]

`2382874` is the first ID in my list.

Here is the M code:

```
let
Source = Sql.Database("server", "db", [Query="SELECT #(lf) [ID]#(lf) ,[company]#(lf) ,[UserID]#(lf)#(tab) 
FROM [dbo].[mysqldb] WHERE [ID] IN (" & Text.Combine(ID_List, ",") & ")" ] )
in
Source
```

I was suggested by someone to convert type of the list to Text before you try to combine the list values, which i did but no luck. Any suggestions would mean a lot.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a list of IDs, then instead of the IN clause, could you use Table.Join? What I mean is convert the List into a Table. #Table( {"ID"} { YOURIDLIST}). Then do a Table.Join with inner join, which I think will be a bit more efficient because you are comparing numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

ID_List is a list of integers and you are using `Text.Combine` on it which is why you are running into this issue because your list does not contain text. They need to be converted into `text`  first before you can apply `Text.Combine`. In the following example, if you don't apply `#"Changed Type"` to `text` you will run into same error.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlSK1YlWMgKTxkqxsQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    Column1 = Text.Combine(#"Changed Type"[Column1],",")
in
    Column1
```